# Strophe Javascript Pubsub Help needed

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, strophe

I need to use the publish subscribe service of Strophe to access nodes my colleague has set up.

Im trying to access a node /Communities/ on the server already set up

Does anyone know of anywhere to get started with Strophe, I have downloaded the test and looked through the api, not having used it before it is a tad confusing. Does anyone know of a tutorial or example I could use?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking out the book [Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery](http://professionalxmpp.com). You can also visit the author's Github account to see some example code and go from there.

https://github.com/metajack/strophejs

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is interested I found a lot of good tutorials and examples in the following book:

[Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery](http://professionalxmpp.com/)

Nice book with a lot of examples and source code, the tutorials are easy to follow as well.